# how to save an outlook mail (.msg) as .html or .pdf using python

Tags: python, outlook, win32com, office-automation, com-automation

I am trying to download an email from outlook sent-items. Currently I am able to save is '.msg' format. Is there anyway through which I can save the mail as '.html' or '.pdf' using python

```
from pathlib import Path
import win32com.client as win32
from datetime import date, timedelta
import os
import glob

# Create output folder
output_dir = Path.cwd()
output_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

# Connect to folder
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application').GetNamespace("MAPI")

# Connect to folder
sent_items = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(5)

# Get the required mail and store it locally
messages = sent_items.items
message = messages.GetLast()
name = str(message.subject)
message.saveas(os.getcwd()+'//'+name+".msg")
```

When I tried to replace .msg with .html or .pdf in the last line, then it is not working. The resultant file generated through html or pdf is displayed as special characters and not the actual .msg format

Comment: Try `message.saveas(os.getcwd()+'//'+name+".html", 5)` (5 is Outlook's format const for olHTML)

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks the above solution works, just one question to add to this. In my mail, there is an image attached in the body. But when I save the mail in .html format, the image is not visible. It's coming as blank. Is there any way on how to get the image displayed as well?

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method for saving messages using the PDF file format. But you can use the [OlSaveAsType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.olsaveastype?view=outlook-pia) enumeration for all available file formats. The HTML format (.html) is available. So, you just need to pass the `olHTML` value for the second parameter in addition to the file path:

```
message.saveas(os.getcwd()+'//'+name+".html", Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olHTML)
```

If you really need to save the message using the PDF file format you may consider using the Word object model for that. The [Document.ExportAsFixedFormat2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat2) method saves a document in PDF or XPS format. Use the [GetInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.getinspector) method to get the inspector where you may retrieve an instance of the Word `Document` object which represents the message body. The [Inspector.WordEditor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.wordeditor) property returns the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. The `WordEditor` property is only valid if the `IsWordMail` method returns `true` and the `EditorType` property is `olEditorWord`. The returned Word `Document` object provides access to most of the Word object model

Answer (score 0):

You may use this:

```
outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

root_folder = outlook.Folders.Item(1)
messages = root_folder.Folders['your folder']
message = messages.Items[0]

#or
#inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
#messages = inbox.items
#message = messages.GetLast()

in_file = os.getcwd()+'//mailfile.doc'

message.SaveAs(in_file , 4) # OlSaveAsType 4 .doc word file

out_file = os.getcwd()+'//mailfile.pdf'

wdFormatPDF = 17
word = Dispatch('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
os.remove(in_file)
```